# move sub folder in one directory to another directory

Tags: linux

I want to move subfolder1 to folder2 in parent directory (I have shown it here). How can I do that in Linux with one line programming?
Thanks!

```
Parent
  Folder 1
     Subfolder1
     Subfolder2
  Folder 2
  Folder 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not sure it's appropriate to answer this, but if you're in 'parent':

```
mv folder1/subfolder2 folder2
```

Or generally,

```
mv path/to/source /path/to/target
```